# Use of trapezodial rule on a iterated integral

Tags: matlab

I want to compute the following integral `int[0,T] int[0,x] F(T,x,y)dy dx` in general for different number of T, say `T=1:0.25:11`. I assume `int[0,x] F(T,x,y)dy` to be a function `g(x)` and apply `trapz` to help evaluate the iterated integral, the following is my code:

`M=T.'*linspace(0,1,100);
fun=@(T,x)integral(@(y)F(T,x,y),0,x);
Points=bsxfun(fun,T',M);
Ans=1/100*trapz(Points,2);`

However, the third line gives an error message: `A and B must be floating point scalars.` I understand the error message, but in my opinion, I do not find out mistakes in my code. Can anyone fix the problem?

Comment: How is `F` defined?

Comment: Your problem is with `integral(@(y)F(T,x,y),0,x);`, it must be able to get vectors as input, and give a vector as an output in order to work with `bsxfun`, I don't see how to easily fix it. But you can always substitute `bsxfun` with a double for if running time is not a concern.